# I'm getting this "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import {MinCont} from "./MinCont";

export const Contain = (props) => {
    let myStyle = {
        minHeight: "100vh",
        margin: "40px auto"
    }
    let empty = {
        color: "red",
    }
    return (
        <div className="container my-3" style={myStyle}>
            <h3 className="my-3">Contain Works!!!</h3>
            <h6 className="my-1" style={empty}>
            {props.contains.length === 0? "No Contain To Display":
            props.contains.map((contain) => {
                return (<MinCont contain={contain} key={contain.sno} onDelete={props.onDelete} />)
            })
            }
            </h6>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the `props` doesn't contain a property with name: `constains` or the `contains` itself is `null`.

You can do one thing.
Try this:

```
//Your code
{props.contains.length === 0? "No Contain To Display": props.contains.map((contain) => { return () }) } ) }

//Now instead of props.contains.length === 0 you can first check if it exists
{props.constains?"yourcode":"else do nothing"}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a valuable answer. :)

Comment: Glad it helped 

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional rendering with Optional chaining (?.)
the props doesn't contain a property.

like this:

```
props?.contains?.length === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate that contains actually is set. In your case its null which results in an error since null.length doesn't exist

You can do it like so

```
props?.contains?.length // either returns the length or undefined
```